# Трудности с созданием класса Контейнера в Haskell

Tags: haskell, контейнеры, containers

Задумал создать класс Контейнера, с тем, чтобы использовать в функциях в качестве аргумента не только, например, список с целочисленным ключем, но и любой тип, который может содержать значения и однозначно их искать по любому сравниваемому (`Eq`) ключу.

```
class Container c where
    at :: (Eq k) => c -> k -> v
```

Трудности начались сразу, как только попытался создать инстанцию класса для того же списка (код нерабочий):

```
{-
instance Container [a] where
    at lst k = lst !! k
-}
```

Выводит следующее сообщение об ошибке:

> ```
> • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘k’
>   ‘k’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>     the type signature for:
>       at :: forall k v. Eq k => [a] -> k -> v
> ```

То есть, ключу, мол, недостаточно быть `Eq`, но он явно должен быть `Int`, как того требует `!!`. Логично, конечно! Но как бы мне вывернуться и реализовать свою идею несмотря на это?

PS Желательно бы в рамках стандартного языка, без расширений.

PPS Требуется, также, критика ответа, данного самим автором вопроса ⬎

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Vector as Vector
import qualified Data.Array as Array

class Container c k | c -> k where
  at :: c a -> k -> a

instance Container [] Int where
  at = (!!)

instance Container (Vector.Vector) Int where
  at = (Vector.!)

instance Ord k => Container (Map.Map k) k where
  at = (Map.!)

instance Array.Ix k => Container (Array.Array k) k where
  at = (Array.!)

main = do print ([1,2,3] `at` 1)
          print (Map.fromList [('x', True), ('y', False)] `at` 'x')
          print (Vector.fromList "abc" `at` 0)
          print (Array.listArray (False, True) ["false", "true"] `at` True)
```

Comment: @extm Не уверен, на сколько кошерно использование `{-# LANGUAGE`, вообще не знаю как к этому относится - недостаточно опыта в Haskell

Comment: @extm Безусловно, лучшей была бы реализация идеи на "чистом" Haskell (если только такое возможно). Обосновать не смогу - чисто эстетическое чувство, возможно оно меня обманывает. Но голос отдал

Comment: @asianirish Последняя редакция языка вышла почти 10 лет назад, очередная на подходе, остается только надеяться, что на этот раз комитет не поскупится на стандартизацию тех расширений, без которых буквально не обойтись.

Answer (score 1):

Тут проблема в том, что `[]` не может быть инстансом вашего класса. Инстансы вашего класса, по определению, должны индексироваться чем угодно с `Eq`, а `[]` индексируется только `Int`ом. Список нельзя индексировать `String`ами, например.

Comment: Может быть как-нибудь хитро класс составить?

Comment: С классом все в порядке, это `[]` к нему не подходит. Модифицируйте `[]`, чтобы он мог индексироваться не только `Int`ами, или вообще не делайте `[]` инстансом своего класса.

Answer (score 0):

Получил то, что хотел:

```
module R.Container
(
    Container (..)
) where


class Container c where
    at :: (Show k, Eq k) => c a -> k -> a


toInt :: (Show s) => s -> Int
toInt r = let s = show r
          in  (read s :: Int)


instance Container [] where
    at arr k = arr !! toInt k

{-
*R.Container> at [1,2,3] 1
2
-}

toBool :: (Show s) => s -> Bool
toBool r = let s = show r
           in  (read s :: Bool)


data MyPair a = MyPair { ifTrue :: a, ifFalse :: a } deriving (Show)


instance Container MyPair where
    at (MyPair a b) k = let yes = toBool k
                        in  if yes then a else b 

{-
*R.Container> let myPair = MyPair 12 13
*R.Container> at myPair True
12
*R.Container> at myPair False
13
-}

toIntPair :: (Show s) => s -> (Int,Int)
toIntPair r = let s = show r
           in  (read s :: (Int,Int))

data Matrix a = Matrix {arr2d :: [[a]]} deriving (Show)


instance Container Matrix where
    at mtrx k = let (f,s) = toIntPair k
                    arrs = arr2d mtrx
                    arr = arrs !! f
                in  arr !! s

{-
*R.Container> let mtrx = Matrix [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,12,11,10]] 
*R.Container> at mtrx (3,1)
12
*R.Container> at mtrx (3,0)
13
-}
```

Пришлось, правда, указать ограничитель типа ключа как `Show`, но не могу найти довода, почему это таки плохо (?)

С благодарностью приму любую самую строгую критику.

Comment: Ну и как оно будет работать при `k ~ Bool`, например?

Comment: @arrowd использую аналогичную функцию `toBool`

Comment: @arrowd добавил в исходник пример использования ключа типа `Bool` для кастомного контейнерного типа MyPair

Comment: @all добавил поиск в двухмерном массиве, где в качестве ключа используется пара целых чисел `(Int, Int)`

Comment: Типобезопасность - одна из сильнейших сторон haskell. Если программа скомпилировалась - то она с большой вероятностью работает правильно. `at (MyPair 12 13) 1` должна падать с ошибкой компиляции, а не с ошибкой времени выполнения, это все-таки не `python`. Также преобразование ключа в строку и обратно - совершенно не нужный удар по производительности. Если выбирать между таким решением и использованием расширений - выбор очевиден. P.S. ограничение `Eq` тут не нужно.

Comment: @extrn ваша правда, буду думать над бескомпромисном (или минимально-компромисном) решением